# How to avoid JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character errors

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm try to fetch Json data from another server which provided me with json format also But I got ***JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character*** errors if I used foreach to loop by difference date.

```
public function getNumber() {

    $begin2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-5 day")));
    $interval2 = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $end2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day")));
    $daterange2 = new DatePeriod($begin2, $interval2, $end2);

    foreach (array_reverse(iterator_to_array($daterange2)) as $val) {

        $url = "ThisIsALinkperiods.action?periods=".$val->format("Ymd1300");
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: Json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $contents = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $contents;
    }
}
```

This is kine of my errors

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 4240 of the JSON data
```

This is my data after respond

```
     [{"betEndtime":null,"betStartime":"2014-01-19 13:00:00","createTime":"2015-12-04 13:00:11","id":100005521
    ,"lotteryOpenStatus":5,"lotteryOpenTime":"2015-12-04 13:00:00","lotteryType":11,"luckNumber":"40615"
    ,"luckNumberSource":"","operatorName":"auto_open_draw","operatorTeleno":"","orderId":"","periods":"201512041300"
    ,"prizeNumCode":0,"prizeNumLevel":1,"productId":11111,"productJson":
..........................................................................
    :"DRAW4","luckDrawDiscount":1,"maxLuckNumLen":5,"maxMoney":2000000,"minLuckNumLen":5,"minMoney":100,"nextStartTime"
    :"2015-11-29 13:00:00","nextStopTime":"2015-11-29 17:45:00","openDrawType":0,"periodUnit":1,"periodUnitNum"
    :1,"price":40,"productCode":"DRAW4","productDesc":"Draw4","productEndTime":20990119163000,"productId"
    :11114,"productType":11,"rate":0,"resTmplProductId":11114,"stopTime":900,"validPeriod":2},"productName"
    :"DRAW4","publicTime":null,"rewardMultiple":0,"updateTime":"2015-11-29 13:11:46","winAmount":0}]
```

Comment: what does the return data look like?

Comment: You know if I don't used Foreach loop It will work as well